# Jersey: "Broken pipe" instead of HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a POST request code that uploads a file. It uploads files correctly but fails with "Broken pipe" instead of 401 Unauthorized that I expect when I provide an incorrect  API key.

I have used Postman to verify that our server sends 401 Unauthorized when a wrong API key is provided.

I am under the impression that my client code still tries to send something to the stream even though the server has already closed the connection after it had sent the 401 Unauthorized.

This is the code I am using:

```
try {
    return target
        .path("storage")
        .path("upload")
        .request()
        .header("Authorization", apiKeyHeader)
        .header("App-Type", type)
        .post(Entity.entity(Files.newInputStream(file.toPath()), APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM), String.class);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // <-- exception comes here
}
```

I have also tried upgrading Jersey to the latest version available: `2.27` but that didn't change anything.

---

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:496)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:767)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:765)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:456)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:357)
at org.comcom.rest.api.resource.v2.AppStorageResource.uploadFile(AppStorageResource.java:70)
```

This is my pom.xml config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The idea is that the header is analysed only after the whole request is sent. You are attaching the file to the request and it takes too much for the request to get to it's destination because of the file size. At some point there is a timeout and this is why you get the broken pipe error, instead of the 401 Error message. The behaviour is normal, and expected. If you try with a smaller file(empty) you will see that you will get the expected error message.

Comment: What technology is used in the receiving end? If it's Jetty then current behaviour could be related to this issue: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/651. I experienced similar issue when communicating Jersey->Jetty. After 401 response Jetty closed the connection but Jersey tried to make a new request with the same connection and received Broken pipe error. It occurred only with big request body.

Comment: @martsraits, this sounds very similar to the problem I was experiencing back then. It was Jetty on the receiving end. Don't work on that code anymore :)